# How to pass a application variables through window object to console using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

```js
window.pageDataLayer.userFeedback.firstName = user ? (user.firstName ? user['firstName'] : '') : ''
window.pageDataLayer.userFeedback.lastName = user ? (user.lastName ? user['secondName'] : '') : ''
window.pageDataLayer.userFeedback.DOB = user ? (user.DOB ? user['DOB'] : '') : ''
```

×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userFeedback' of undefined

How to save the application parameters to window objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create the `pageDataLayer`-Object first.
Right now you are trying to access the object `userFeedback` of the object `pageDataLayer` - which does not exist.

Also, there is no difference between accessing the `user` properties with dot-notation or in square bracktes (`user.firstName` is the same as `user['firstName']`) so you can omit the duplicate ternary operator there.

Lastly, and only in case your `user` object is on the global scope, you will get an error with your syntax if it does not exist - so you should access it with `window` as well.

So all in all, this should do the trick:

```js
window.pageDataLayer = {
  userFeedback: {
    firstName: window.user ? user.firstName : '',
    lastName: window.user ? user.lastName : '',
    DOB: window.user ? user.DOB : ''
  }
}

console.log(window.pageDataLayer);
```